# MySQL: выборка ближайших точек (OpenGIS)

Tags: gps, sql, mysql

Есть MySQL база данных со следующей таблицей:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `my_table` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` text NOT NULL,
  `coords` point NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Данные в нее вставляются вот так:

```
INSERT INTO `my_table` VALUES
(NULL, 'name1', POINT(50.456257,30.511237)),
(NULL, 'name2', POINT(50.456230,30.511425)),
(NULL, 'name3', POINT(50.456244,30.510902));
```

Теперь собственно задача - необходимо произвести выборку из таблицы только тех записей, которые находятся не дальше 5 метров от точки A (координаты точки известны).

Answer (score 2):

Материал тут: [Пространственные расширения](http://www.rldp.ru/mysql/mysqlpro/spat.htmz).

Единственное, что смог раскопать это:

```
X(p) - Возвращает значение X-координаты для p как число двойной точности.
Y(p) - Возвращает значение Y-координаты для p как число двойной точности.

Пример:
SET @pt = 'Point(56.7 53.34)';
mysql> SELECT Y(GeomFromText(@pt));
+----------------------+
| Y(GeomFromText(@pt)) |
+----------------------+
| 53.34                |
+----------------------+
```

Таким образом можно написать след запрос:

```
select * from my_table where 
sqrt(pow(Y(coords),2) + pow(X(coords),2)) <= $searchRadius
```

Но должно быть какое то не такое решение, потому что поиск в заданном радиусе - довольно нужная штука.

Comment: Подумал, что такое решение не прокатит.

Поскольку здесь точки в координатах на земле, а расстояние у тебя в метрах.

В приведенном мной материале есть какое-то упоминание о "конфигурации", и там есть функция distance, только она на вход не точки принимает, а как раз "конфигурации". Покапай в этом направлении.

Comment: В том то и проблема, что необходимо конвертировать систему отчета из долготы и широты в систему отчета, которая будет привязана к местности и можно будет сказать, что она "плоская". Тогда возможно уже использовать метры. А использовать разные системы отчета неверно здесь в корне.

Приведу пример. есть нулевой меридиан, а есть 359-ый. Думаю проблема уже понятна, но кроме этого они находятся на расстоянии одного меридиана друг от друга. Но в метрах в каждой своей точке они будут находиться на разном расстоянии друг от друга и на полюсах будут иметь нулевое расстояние, а на экваторе максимальное

Comment: Нужно математическую модель разработать со своей логикой. И думаю что если хранить долготу и широту, а искать по радиусу, то это нужно делать логику, которая будет хранится в хранимых процедурах. Доставать всю таблицу на уровень приложения довольно затратно, а переводит радиус в какой-то формат долготы и широты на уровне приложения - получится не точно, да и как-то глупо чтоли.. :)